# Is there any way where i can get a link of the of a user profile picture on discord that is always updated without changing the link?

Tags: html, web, discord

I was wondering, is there any way that I can get the profile picture of a user in discord, without changing the link to use it in a web page? For instead of changing every time the link I use the same so I don't need to always look if they have changed the profile picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When somebody uploads an image to Discord, it generates a random URL for that image. Unless you can create an algorithm that gets the URL for a certain user, the answer is no.